# Declared Variable not getting recognised in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm new to kotlin app developement. I created a app, where i declared a variable named **nameInput** in **activity.xml** file. But when i try to use that in main file, it is showing error that variable is not declared. I had imported everything that is required, but still it is happening
Here is my snapshot from activity.xml:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameInput" //this variable
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/input_hint_text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/helperMessage" />
```

Here is my main file where i am using that variable:

```
package com.example.birthdaygreetingapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {

    val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()

    val intent = Intent(this, BirthdayGreetingActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(BirthdayGreetingActivity.NAME_EXTRA, name)
    startActivity(intent)
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well that works only on `kotlin-synthetic` which is deprecated you need to use other alternative like findViewById(), viewbinding,  databinding

Answer (score 2):

`nameInput` is the `id` of your `EditText` view and **not** the variable name. In order to use it in your activity, you need to either use `findViewById`:
`var nameInput = findViewById(R.id.nameInput)` 

or use Kotlin synthetic imports:
`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.nameInput`, assuming your layout file is named `activity_main.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `nameInput` is not declared in your code.

If you are new to Android use `findViewById` method.

After the layout inflate you can find the views in your xml `activity_main`

```
val mNameInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameInput)
```

Do not use kotlin synthetic because is officialy deprecated and will be removed in the near future.